# Add crypto++ Library to codeblocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I'm new to C++ coding. I was working with security applications where i needed to use Crypto++ library with my code developed in codeblocks. But every time i build i get the following below errors(have not included all the errors). guess i'm not able to link the library with my code.

```
||=== Build: Debug in CryptoQc (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
obj\Debug\src\aes.o||In function `main':|
D:\cryptography\C++ Code\CryptoQc\src\aes.cpp|16|undefined reference to `CryptoPP::OS_GenerateRandomBlock(bool, unsigned char*, unsigned int)'|
D:\cryptography\C++ Code\CryptoQc\src\aes.cpp|21|undefined reference to `CryptoPP::SimpleKeyingInterface::SetKeyWithIV(unsigned char const*, unsigned int, unsigned char const*, unsigned int)'|
D:\cryptography\C++ Code\CryptoQc\src\aes.cpp|27|undefined reference to `CryptoPP::StringSinkTemplate<std::string>::StringSinkTemplate(std::string&)'|
obj\Debug\src\aes.o||In function `ZN8CryptoPP21SimpleKeyingInterfaceD2Ev':|
D:\cryptography\C++ Code\CryptoQc\include\cryptlib.h|602|undefined reference to `vtable for CryptoPP::SimpleKeyingInterface'|
obj\Debug\src\aes.o||In function `ZN8CryptoPP19BlockTransformationD2Ev':|
```

Comment: There should be a linker settings tab (or similar) in your project settings. There you should be able to add libraries to link with.

Comment: I will advise you to take a look at [msy2](https://www.msys2.org/), this makes dependency management on windows a lot easier, just use pacman

Comment: @bluedragon i wana use crypto++ library in codeblocks editor. after installation msys2 and use pacman and install successfully this library but codeblocks not detect this library, how can i do?